# Extjs 4 get index of record that is not loaded yet from remote store

Tags: load, store, record, extjs4.2

I have a store with, for example, 3000 records and my pageSize is 250. I also have a unique value from one of the records (lets say `product_id = 2333`), but this record is not loaded yet, so the `store.findRecord("product_id", product_id)` will return null.

My question is, how do I get the index of a record that is not loaded yet, so I can load the correct page after getting the index?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the onload method of the store:

```
store.on('load',function(component,records){
   //here all the records are loaded, so:
   component.findRecord('prop',value)//will return your record
  //here you can load the page you need
},this,{single:true});
```

You can't find a record if it doesn't already exist, the only method is to wait untill the store is loaded.

the property `single:true` passed as option simply indicates that this function will execute a single time every time you set it on load listener.

Keep attention, if you omit that your store load will execute all the listeners you append to that.

If you want a perfect way to do that:

```
view.mask('loading the page...');

store.on('load',function(component,records){
       component.findRecord('prop',value)//will return your record
      //here you can load the page you need
      page.load(); //simply example
      view.unmask();
},this,{single:true});
store.load();
```

or

```
view.mask('loading the page...');

    store.load(function(records){
           store.findRecord('prop',value)//will return your record
          //here you can load the page you need
          page.load(); //simply example
          view.unmask();
    });
```